# How to set a cookie in my domain while my app is in Iframe so I can access it when the client opens my app throw my domain?

Tags: javascript, angular, spring

I have an angular app hosted on a domain `"ourDomain"` and it will be in an iframe on a client web-app 
that hosted on `"clientDomain"`.

I am trying to set a cookie in my domain but I am getting the following warning that prevents saving the cookie in the browser console  :

**A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at "ourDomain" was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.**

I have tried to set the cookie using this library 
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service](http://I%20have%20tried%20to%20set%20the%20cookie%20using%20this%20library%20%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service)
and set the domain name while setting the cookie like this :

```
cookieService.set('key', 'value', 2, '/', 'ourDomain', true, 'Lax');
```

I also tried to make a REST call to my spring API with a header that contains `{withCredentials: true}`

and the response header contains

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("username", req.getHeader("Origin"));
cookie.setMaxAge(2 * 24 * 60 * 60); // expires in 2 days
cookie.setSecure(true);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setDomain("dev.siliconexpert.com");
response.addCookie(cookie);
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "ourDomain");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

But unfortunately, I am still getting the same warning .

So is there something wrong with my solutions? or, is there another solution to get that done?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is running on within an `iframe` on a different site, that means all of its cookies are in a third-party or cross-site context. Therefore with the upcoming changes in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge those cookies will need to be marked as `SameSite=None; Secure`.

The `ngx-cookie-service` library does not support the new `None` value and is currently looking for a new maintainer, so it's unlikely to be updated soon. However, looking at the server side code you've provided, that looks like something else.

Either use your server side library to add the `Secure` attribute and `SameSite` attribute with a `None` value, or use the `SetHeader()` method to write the `Set-Cookie` header yourself.

You can find more context at https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained and some examples on https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples